How do I show results of a API call on screen Jetpack Compose
This is code for Home.kt
package com.example.littlelemonandroid

import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.detectTapGestures
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.absoluteOffset
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.wrapContentSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.CircleShape
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.outlined.Search
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TextField
import androidx.compose.material3.TextFieldDefaults
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.scale
import androidx.compose.ui.focus.FocusManager
import androidx.compose.ui.focus.FocusRequester
import androidx.compose.ui.focus.focusRequester
import androidx.compose.ui.focus.onFocusChanged
import androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.pointerInput
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalFocusManager
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController
import androidx.room.Room
import com.example.littlelemonandroid.ui.theme.Black
import com.example.littlelemonandroid.ui.theme.DarkGray
import com.example.littlelemonandroid.ui.theme.Green
import com.example.littlelemonandroid.ui.theme.LittleLemonAndroidTheme
import com.example.littlelemonandroid.ui.theme.White
import com.example.littlelemonandroid.ui.theme.Yellow
import io.ktor.client.HttpClient
import io.ktor.client.call.body
import io.ktor.client.engine.android.Android
import io.ktor.client.plugins.contentnegotiation.ContentNegotiation
import io.ktor.client.request.get
import io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json.json

//@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun Home(navController: NavHostController)  {

    val searchPhrase = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    val focusManager: FocusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    var isAnyTextFieldFocused by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var isFocused by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }

    val context = LocalContext.current
    val database by lazy {
        Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "database").build()
    }


    LittleLemonAndroidTheme {

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(White)
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectTapGestures {
                        if (isAnyTextFieldFocused) {
                            focusManager.clearFocus()
                        }
                    }
                }
        ) {
            Row(
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(start = 110.dp)
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(100.dp)
                        .wrapContentSize(unbounded = true)
                ) {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.logo),
                        contentDescription = "Little Lemon Logo",
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(150.dp)
                    )
                }
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(100.dp)
                        .wrapContentSize(unbounded = true)
                        .clip(CircleShape)
                        .padding(start = 30.dp)
                        .clickable {
                            navController.navigate(Profile.route)
                        }
                ) {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.profile),
                        contentDescription = "Little Lemon Logo",
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(60.dp)
                            .clip(CircleShape)
                            .scale(2.0f)
                            .absoluteOffset(y = 7.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Green)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(start = 15.dp, end = 15.dp, bottom = 20.dp)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(id = R.string.app_title),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium,
                    color = Yellow,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .size(50.dp)
                )
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(id = R.string.app_city),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleSmall,
                    color = White,
                )
                Row(
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                )   {
                    Text(
                        text = stringResource(id = R.string.app_description),
                        color = White,
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
                        fontSize = 15.sp,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Left,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .weight(0.7f)
                            .padding(top = 20.dp)
                    )
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.hero_image),
                        contentDescription = "Hero Image",
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(height = 130.dp, width = 150.dp)
                            .weight(0.5f)
                            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                    )
                }
                TextField(
                    value = searchPhrase.value,
                    onValueChange = {searchPhrase.value = it},
                    placeholder = {
                        Text(
                            text = "Enter search phrase",
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelMedium,
                            color = DarkGray,
                            fontSize = 18.sp,
                        )
                    },
                    leadingIcon = {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Search,
                            contentDescription = "Search Icon",
                            tint = Black
                        )
                    },
                    colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
                        unfocusedContainerColor = White,
                        focusedContainerColor = White
                    ),
                    textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.labelMedium,
                    singleLine = true,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(
                            top = 15.dp,
                        )
                        .size(50.dp)
                        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(6.dp))
                        .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                        .onFocusChanged { focusState ->
                            isFocused = focusState.isFocused
                            isAnyTextFieldFocused = isFocused
                        }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

suspend fun fetchMenu() : List<MenuItemNetwork> {
    val httpClient = HttpClient(Android)    {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json()
        }
    }

    val dataURL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Meta-Mobile-Developer-PC/Working-With-Data-API/main/menu.json"
    val menuNetwork : MenuNetwork = httpClient.get(dataURL).body()

    return menuNetwork.menu
}

This is MainActivity.kt
package com.example.littlelemonandroid

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsets
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.statusBars
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.windowInsetsPadding
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.core.view.WindowCompat
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import com.example.littlelemonandroid.ui.theme.LittleLemonAndroidTheme
import com.example.littlelemonandroid.ui.theme.White

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        enableEdgeToEdge()

        setContent {
            LittleLemonAndroidTheme {
                Scaffold(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .windowInsetsPadding(WindowInsets.statusBars)
                        .background(White)
                ) { innerPadding ->
                    Box()   {
                        val navController = rememberNavController()
                        Navigation(navController = navController)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

This is Network.kt
package com.example.littlelemonandroid

import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class MenuNetwork(
    @SerialName("menu")
    val menu: List<MenuItemNetwork>
)

@Serializable
data class MenuItemNetwork(
    @SerialName("id")
    val id: Int,

    @SerialName("title")
    val title: String,

    @SerialName("description")
    val description: String,

    @SerialName("price")
    val price: Double,

    @SerialName("image")
    val image: String,

    @SerialName("category")
    val category: String,
)   {
    fun toMenuItemRoom() = MenuItemRoom(id, title, description, price, image, category)
}

This is Database.kt
package com.example.littlelemonandroid

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import androidx.room.Query
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Entity
data class MenuItemRoom (
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    val description: String,
    val price: Double,
    val image: String,
    val category: String,
)

@Dao
interface MenuItemDao   {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM MenuItemRoom")
    fun getAll(): LiveData<List<MenuItemRoom>>

    @Insert
    fun insertAll(vararg menuItems: MenuItemRoom)

    @Query("SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MenuItemRoom) == 0")
    fun isEmpty(): Boolean
}

@Database(entities = [MenuItemRoom::class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase  : RoomDatabase()    {
    abstract fun menuItemDao(): MenuItemDao
}

How do I display the result of fetchMenu as shown below
App image
This is what the api call made in fetchMenu function gives:
{
  "menu": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Greek Salad",
      "description": "The famous greek salad of crispy lettuce, peppers, olives, our Chicago.",
      "price": "10",
      "image": "https://github.com/Meta-Mobile-Developer-PC/Working-With-Data-API/blob/main/images/greekSalad.jpg?raw=true",
      "category": "starters"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Lemon Desert",
      "description": "Traditional homemade Italian Lemon Ricotta Cake.",
      "price": "10",
      "image": "https://github.com/Meta-Mobile-Developer-PC/Working-With-Data-API/blob/main/images/lemonDessert%202.jpg?raw=true",
      "category": "desserts"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "Grilled Fish",
      "description": "Our Bruschetta is made from grilled bread that has been smeared with garlic and seasoned with salt and olive oil.",
      "price": "10",
      "image": "https://github.com/Meta-Mobile-Developer-PC/Working-With-Data-API/blob/main/images/grilledFish.jpg?raw=true",
      "category": "mains"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "title": "Pasta",
      "description": "Penne with fried aubergines, cherry tomatoes, tomato sauce, fresh chili, garlic, basil & salted ricotta cheese.",
      "price": "10",
      "image": "https://github.com/Meta-Mobile-Developer-PC/Working-With-Data-API/blob/main/images/pasta.jpg?raw=true",
      "category": "mains"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "title": "Bruschetta",
      "description": "Oven-baked bruschetta stuffed with tomatoes and herbs.",
      "price": "10",
      "image": "https://github.com/Meta-Mobile-Developer-PC/Working-With-Data-API/blob/main/images/bruschetta.jpg?raw=true",
      "category": "starters"
    }
  ]
} 

Tried running fetchMenu on runBlocking and LaunchedEffect but its not working. I mainly need to be able to do things: 1.) Call the function, and 2.) Store the Data in database and display the result. I'm new to Jetpack Compose if their are other suggestions please do say so.

What you need is a View Model.
The view model will provide the UI with the necessary data and responds to any requests originating from the UI. It has its own coroutine scope to run code concurrently to the UI.
The UI will never know anything about the database. That is encapsulated in the view model. Instead the view model will retrieve the data from the database and exposes a Flow of the data that is always updated when something changes in the database (feel free to choose a more appropriate name for the class):
class MyVieModel(
    private val dao: MenuItemDao,
) : ViewModel() {
    val menuItems: StateFlow<List<MenuItemRoom>> = dao.getAll().stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
        initialValue = emptyList(),
    )
}

For that to work you must change the return type of your dao's getAll() function to Flow<List<MenuItemRoom>>. You do not want to use LiveData with Compose, instead all dao functions that query the database should return a Flow. You probably want to change that for isEmpty() as well.
In your Home composable the first thing you should do is this:
val viewModel: MyVieModel = viewModel()
val menuItems by viewModel.menuItems.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

The first line retrieves a view model instance. This will not work right now because it is yet unknown how to provide the dao property to the view model's constructor. I won't go into much detail here, but you have to either provide a view model factory OR construct the database object in the view model and retrieve the needed context from the AndroidViewModel that you could inherit from instead, OR simply let a dependency injection framework like Hilt handle all of that for you. I would prefer the latter. It takes some time to set up, but when it's working everything else becomes much easier.
The second line converts the view model Flow into a Compose State. You need the gradle dependency androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose for that.
You can now use this List<MenuItemRoom> anway you want to display in your UI.

Now, when you want to call fetchMenu and save the return value in the database, that can be placed in the view model as well:
fun fetchMenu() {
    val httpClient = HttpClient(Android) {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json()
        }
    }
    val dataURL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Meta-Mobile-Developer-PC/Working-With-Data-API/main/menu.json"

    viewModelScope.launch {
        val menuItems: List<MenuItemRoom> = httpClient
            .get(dataURL)
            .body<MenuNetwork>()
            .menu
            .map(MenuItemNetwork::toMenuItemRoom)
        dao.insertAll(menuItems)
    }
}

I made several adjustments to this function:

First off, the view model should never expose suspend functions. Instead all code that suspends should be wrapped in a new coroutine launched in the viewModelScope.

.map(MenuItemNetwork::toMenuItemRoom) transforms the List<MenuItemNetwork> to a List<MenuItemRoom>.

This list is then inserted into the database. You need to change the parameter of insertAll to be a List instead of vararg parameter for that. Also the function should be a suspend function. It should look like this:
suspend fun insertAll(menuItems: List<MenuItemRoom>)


View model functions usually do not need to return anything because any changes they effect should be reflected in the flows instead.


You can now call fetchMenu from your UI. Just to make sure to call it from a callback like a Button's onClick. That will save the data in the database and your view model's menuItems flow will automatically update with the new data that was just saved in the database. Your Home composable's menuItems variable will also update automatically and triggers a recomposition which will update your UI according to this new data.

If this helped you solve your problem you can accept this answer by ticking the checkmark left to it. This helps other who have the same problem finding this answer.
